# What's the best way to setup local DNS at a cloud host using BIND?

Tags: cloud-computing, internal-dns, bind

I run a few application clusters within a cloud-based host.  We've grown to the point where I need some sort of internal DNS scheme to keep all of the servers straight.  I'd like to run a server with BIND9 installed to solve this problem.

Right now, the internal team members VPN into the cloud and then connect on each respective server's private interface.  I'd like to modify the VPN server to use this new BIND DNS server.  How do I configure BIND so that I can provide internal entries for my servers, but also allow anyone who is connected via VPN to still access external sites such as google.com or serverfault.com?

All external DNS entries for my load balancers are handled offsite, so there is no need for the BIND server to provide any DNS capabilities to the outside world.

I will be using BIND on Ubuntu 10.04, so answers in the context of Debian are preferred (but I'll take what I can get).

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up bind to be the master DNS server for your 'cloud' zone and then have it forward other requests on to whichever DNS servers you currently use. Have a look at the [Ubuntu Bind 9 documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto) for the configuration specifics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I managed to get that far on my own, but I'm looking for advice from someone who has done this before to make sure I configure it properly.

Comment: @GregB: I've done what you want to do. The article I linked to should help you get there. If you have any specific questions ask them on SF. That's what it's here for.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give this strategy a try, [Using Amazon EC2 Metadata as a Simple DNS](http://dysinger.net/2008/10/13/using-amazon-ec2-metadata-as-a-simple-dns/).